# PHP templates not found in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, templates

I am new to symfony and I want to use PHP templating engine. Below are the steps I followed to make it work.

**1.Enabled PHP templating engine in config.yml**

```
templating:
    engines: ['twig', 'php']
```

**2.Defined my controller path and defaults in routing.yml**

```
hello:
    path:      /hello/{name}
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Hello:index, name:World }
```

**3.Created HelloController.php**

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class HelloController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return $this->render('hello/name.html.php', array(
            'name'=>$name
        ));
    }
}
```

**4.Created a view \app\Resources\views\Hello\name.html.php**

```
<!-- app/Resources/views/Hello/name.html.php -->
Hello <?php echo $name ?>!
```

but when I try to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello, it shows me below error

> The template "hello/name.html.php" does not exist.
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException

I changed template folder name from 'Hello' to 'hello' but still same error. Also tried to render template like this

```
return $this->render(
    'AppBundle:Hello:index.html.php',
    array('name' => $name)
);
```

but no luck, I must be missing something here. Can someone please guide me to right direction?

**Note:** *hello/name.html.twig* is loading without any error

Thank you!

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/PHP.html
this page says that you need to use annotation:
/**
 * @Template(engine="php")
 */
Did you try to use it?

Comment: folder name should be `hello` and clear the cache after that change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your template is in app/Resources/views/Hello/ folder, you should use this notation:

```
$response = $this->render(':Hello:name.html.php');
```

If you would move it to src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Hello folder, then use

```
$response = $this->render('AppBundle:Hello:name.html.php');
```