# symfony 4 php template location

Tags: php, symfony, templates, symfony4

Please help, symfony 4 cant find php template.

The error is **The template "::test/index.html.php" does not exist.**

Controller :

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class TestController extends Controller
{

    public function number()
    {
        $number = mt_rand(0, 100);

        // return new Response(
        //     '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        // );
        return $this->render("test/number.html.php",
            array('number' => $number));
    }

    function index() {
        return $this->render("test/index.html.php");
    }
}
```

Directories:

- templates/

  - test/

    - index.html.php
    - number.html.php

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `twig` as a template engine?

Comment: no i'm using PHP template, have enabled it in config

Comment: Possible duplicate, look at this post : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738155/php-templates-not-found-in-symfony)

Comment: there is no `app/` folder in symfony 4 , and there is `templates/` folder for templates

Comment: Also dont work, tried the link and changed:         `return $this->render("App:Test:index.html.php");`

Comment: @Superbiji, can you show your `namespaces` of your Controller?

Comment: it's App\Controller

Comment: Try this http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#template-suffix

Answer (score 3):

The shortcuts with the **bundle:directory:filename** notation is not used anymore in Symfony 4. Instead use real path's relative to the templates directory or for bundles use the syntax with the @ prefix. For more information: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#template-naming-and-locations

If your error occurs from a third party bundle then this bundle is not ready to work with Symfony 4. You could then fork the bundle and change the template notation in the controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You should do package installation with composer for PHP Engine. Try cleaning the cache. Check the permissions (755 or 777) of the "Templates" directory.

http://symfony.com/doc/master/templating/PHP.html

Answer (score 0):

Place for php templates is src\Resources\Views